# Can we use single Azure Event Hub for different customer without compromising other customer data?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-eventhub, azure-eventgrid

I have different customers data resides in my COSMOS Db. I need to push that data into Azure event hub and at receiver end I have different consumers to consume their own data. Should I use single Azure Event Hub for all the customers or create multiple event hubs?
Please suggest me the best approach to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Event Hub does not offer any degree of data isolation. If you include information to make a distinction between customers in the message you can then use that information when processing the data. Other than that, your only option is to use multiple Event Hubs.

You might be tempted to use partitions to seperate data of different customers but I wouldn't because it hurts the scalability and there is a low maximum of number of partitions.

The way Event Hubs work is that the messages are spread over partitions. You can create different consumer groups but they will all see the same messages.

Do you really want your customers to directly consume messages from the Event Hub? If so, use different Event Hubs. If not, do the processing yourself and redirect customer specific messages to seperated downstream processors. For example, you could send the messages to seperated azure services bus queues or topics, one for each customer.

Or, as Anupam Chand suggest, you can push the data to the customers using something like Event Grid.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I am currently not looking for multi-tenant system my scenario is like I have logs corresponding to different customers and the customer id is in json log message. Now once I send that log to event hub I want each customer should be able to get only his logs from event hub.

Comment: Rather than depend on the customers to fetch their own logs, why not push the logs to them? In this case, you should be using something like Eventgrid. You can then filter out respective customers data and based on some properties and push only that data to them.

Comment: @manishraghu Whether you call it a tenant or a customer doesn't change the fact that it cannot be done the way you like it. But I've added some options to my answer

Comment: @AnupamChand indeed, that is also a possibility.

Comment: @AnupamChand I am working on integration with Logrhythm that supports Event hub. so I have multiple customers having SIEM installed to fetch data from event hub

Comment: Thanks. Then indeed you would need multiple Eventhubs. Authentication to receive is at the Eventhub level, not at the partition level. You would have to keep the authentication for each customer separate so there is not risk of one reading another's data. @Peter's answer is correct.